float and NumericProperty in Kivy
I'm currently working on a Kivy project and I need to compare a Scatter position to the Screen size.
I've tried this line of code where self is the Scatter itself and GameScreen is the name of the Screen:
if self.pos[0] < 0 or self.pos[0] > GameScreen.width or self.pos[1] < 0 or self.pos[1] > GameScreen.height:
    # do something

The terminal yields this error:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty'.
I have also tried to mask the scatter position as a NumericProperty like this:
NumericProperty(self.pos[0])

but I get the same error as before:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty' and 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty'
Finally I tried to transform the Screen width to a float by casting it like this:
float(GameScreen.width)

but I get the error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty'.
Do you have any advice or do you know how to do it?

Seems like your NumericProperty needs to be declared at the class level in order to use it: https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/9z8aos/new_to_kivy_need_help_with_operands_please/

You need to use an instance of GameScreen, not the class itself. Somewhere in your code you must create an instance of GameScreen. Use the width property of that instance.
